# Edit image metadata in a table

Tags: images, metadata, table, edit

I need to edit the metadata (eg title, tags) of several images. I can do that one by one in the explorer properties but that takes time. In the tools I know (file and image managers) you can see these attributes if you make that column visible but I'm looking for a solution where I can see and edit these in table form. I'm a big fan of voidtools everything, the author promised this feature a long time ago but it hasn't reached the feature set yet. Is there any other tool where you can edit these in table form ?
The image below is from an example in everything but is not editable.
https://ibb.co/fSLQD2f